# Dimensions and Metrics Explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is there a way I can integrate the [dimensions and Metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) in my app (which allows me to create extraction commands and then use the Analytics Reporting API v4 to get the reports) cause I don't want to have to go and check on the website every time to make sure I am not choosing incompatible Dimensions and Metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all of the valid dimensions and metrics from the [Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) however at this time there is no way of checking if the dimensions and metrics are compatible with each other.  The only way to do that is to send the request or as you said check the [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).

I have asked the team about this quite often over the years.  They say they would like to add something like it at some point.  However I think its probably low on there priority list.

Answer: No there is no way to programmatically check if dimensions and metrics are valid together before sending the request.

Comment: Does anybody know if this is still the case or if there is now a way to query for compatible dimensions and metrics. The explorer here enables/disables other dimensions and metrics as you make selections so it seems like this data is available somewhere.

Comment: it is still the case.   The only way to programmatically see if a metadata item is valid is to send the request to the api and wait for it to return an error.